# Mockito doReturn returns different value based on the parameters of mocked object method call

Tags: mockito

I have a nested class `Foo` which has a field called `Bar` and a method call `getBarBasedOnMusic(Music music)`.

want to do the mocking to achieve the below behavior:

```
doReturn(some_result).when(Foo.class).getBarBasedOnMusic(Music.getAuthor == "Beethoven")
```

Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: with `.getBar()` you mean `getBarBasedOnMusic(Music music)`? Can you maybe provide the source code of your class you want to test

Comment: @rieckpil yes you are right. The source code has dependencies so I have to abstract the problem out.